# Given $(X,A)$，$(Y,B)$ such that $X/A$ and $Y/B$ are homotopy equivalent,are their relative homology groups isomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose that $(X,A)$，$(Y,B)$ are pairs of topological spaces. If $X/A$ and $Y/B$ are homotopy equivalent, are $H_*(X,A;\mathbb{Z})$ isomorphic to $H_*(Y,B;\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Comment: if they are good pair , i.e if A is deformation retract of an open set of X, and same true for Y , then their relative homology groups are isomorphic

Comment: Is it true if the inclusions $A \rightarrow X $ and $B \rightarrow Y $ are all cofibrations? How to proof that? Or do you know some references about this?

Comment: I donot know such results, I need to think.

Comment: You might want to think about the inclusion of a subcomplex into a CW complex to get an idea for how to prove it, that's the standard case.

Comment: If a inclusion $\emptyset\neq W\subseteq Z$ is a cofibration, then $H_*(Z,W;\mathbb{Z})\cong \tilde{H}(Z/W,\mathbb{Z})$. So your claim holds if both inclusions are cofibrations.